# The [readied-action] and [triggered-actions] tags

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a [readied-action](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/readied-action) tag (101 questions tagged, 43 asked this year) with the following guidance:

> An action "held" to react to an anticipated circumstance.

There is also a [triggered-actions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triggered-actions) tag (only 12 questions tagged, only 2 asked this year) and no guidance.

Are these two tags distinct? If not, should one be a synonym of the other? Otherwise, if so, what should be the tag guidance for [triggered-actions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triggered-actions)?

Answer (score 3):

I think "readied action" is fine as-is, and "triggered-actions" could probably use a usage guide if it's meaningful. My gut says that it doesn't have meaning beyond "stuff happens when other stuff happens" and it's impossible to be a system-agnostic expert on the concept.

In other words, they are not synonyms, [readied-action](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/readied-action) should stay, and [triggered-actions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triggered-actions) should probably be removed unless someone can make a usage guide that merits keeping it.

Comment: It had one usage in dungeon world which I removed. (In DW, all mechanical actions are triggered, so it's a superfluous usage of this tag as opposed to a "moves" tag or whatnot.) That leaves us with just usage in D&D which ought to help us figure out usage guidance or meaningfulness.

Answer (score 1):

#### The difference is the active choice in priming the action

A readied action is an action that a player would choose to hold onto until a trigger occurs, at which point the action is performed. They have to have the forethought to expect some circumstance that they wish to react to.

A triggered-action doesn't require that kind of forethought. It's an action that is effectively "always on stand-by" without you needing to do anything.

#### Take for example, attacks of opportunity

For many games, an attack of opportunity would be a kind of triggered action because you don't have to explicitly have to be on the look-out for a situation to arise to take one. An enemy moves out of your reach, or casts a spell in front of you, or drinks a potion while engaged with you and it triggers a response.

#### That could be the tag guidance for triggered-actions

Triggered actions are actions that you take in response to some stimulus without having to explicitly anticipate that circumstance beforehand.